# CSS Navigation alignment

Tags: css, html

Im trying to create a simple CSS navigation only im having some trouble.

The idea is when you hover over a link the drop downs appear below (see example).

The subcategory links need to be right aligned within the "wrap" container so theyre right aligned with the primary navigation only I cant seem to fget it to work no matter what I try.

I hope this makes sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/QdhsC/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what should be where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ul.subnav li  { float: right; }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this. Try this in your css.

```
ul.subnav li {float:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QdhsC/8/